# Discount code not working on mobile in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.9.3.2

I have implemeted discount code section on cart page. Design for Discount Code section is different for both desktop and mobile. I have called discount code block two times on single page for desktop and mobile.

Functionality for mobile is working fine, But not working in desktop.

Please find the below code for mobile :

```
<div class="your-cart sidebar mob-only proceed-mob">
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('totals'); ?>
<?php if (!$this->hasError()): ?>
    <div class="cart-checkout-methods">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods'); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php //echo $this->getChildHtml('coupon'); ?>
```

Find the below code for desktop: -

```
<div class="staticpage_sidebar sidebar desktop-only">
       <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('totals'); ?>
       <?php if (!$this->hasError()): ?>
            <div class="cart-checkout-methods">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods'); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('coupon'); ?>
</div>
```

Where am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make **Stop Further Rules Processing** dropdown to YES.

```
Promotions > ShoppingCart Price Rules > Rule Name > Actions > Stop Further Rules Processing -- YES.
```

If you have multiple Shopping cart rules it may conflict the other, then set priority to the each shopping cart rule and revert Stop further rules processing to No.

Hope it helps. !!!